# Using AngularJS routing and loading controllers on demand using requirejs

Tags: routes, angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to use AngularJS and RequireJS in combination. I would like to use the `$routeProvider` service and avoid having to load all the controllers for my views on application startup. For that, I tried the following:

```
define(['require', 'angular', 'appModule'], function (require, angular, app) {
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/sites', {templateUrl: '/Site/GetSitesView', controller: function() {
            require(['sitesController'], function(SitesController) {
                return new SitesController();
            })
        }})
    }]);
});
```

Unfortunately, that did not work for me. There are no errors. The JS file containing the controller is being loaded properly but I cannot see the data bound value in the rendered view. I was wondering whether I could assign the value of `controller` in some other way that would wait for the asynchronous call (to load the JS file) to complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: The only way to do this is to get hold of $controllerProvider. I have a working solution here: https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers

Comment: @matys84pl that's actually along the lines of what I was thinking to do. Thanks for sharing this. One thing though, I went through the code and saw that you are loading templates using the Require Text plugin, is that the only supported way of loading templates using your library? What if I want to load the template from a URL on the server, would that work?

Comment: It depends if the url is relative to your app.. in other words is it on the same domain? If not then I think you would have to use some kind of proxy to achive that (to load files from other domain).

Comment: Thanks matys84pl. This really helped. Just wondering why your reply is not marked as answer (Kassem) ?

Comment: @matys84pl can we use it for services loading also?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the solution **[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx)**

You need to define a resolve property on each route and assign it a function that returns a promise. The function can dynamically load the script contains the target controller and resolve the promise once the loading is complete. In this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx), **Dan Wahlin** shows how to use convention over configuration to have more practical routing.