# How to use Require JS in Angular JS Application?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I need to implement dynamic loading in my Angular JS App. I am trying to load some js plugin files and css files.  I learned Require JS is the best for this job. But couldt find any straight forward examples. Any help appreciated.

Comment: search for angulejs requirejs seed on github, you can find many way to implement it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155457/using-angularjs-routing-and-loading-controllers-on-demand-using-requirejs/21430185#21430185

Comment: You may find [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) interesting.